# file upload with nodejs koa co-busboy

Tags: node.js, koa, co

I use [co-busyboy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co-busboy) to parse file fields when uploading files using KOA.  The official example looks like this:

```
var parse = require('co-busboy')
var parts = parse(this);
var part; 
while (part = yield parts) {
   if(!part.length) //it is a stream
     part.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('some file.txt'));
}
```

For some reasons, I want to save all of "part" streams into an array, and perform the actual files writing when all of file streams are fetched. i.e.:

```
var parse = require('co-busboy');
var parts = parse(this);
var part;
var partArrays = [];
var cnt = 0;
while(part = yield parts){
   partArray[cnt++] = part;
}
//after some processing, I perform the writing
for(file in partArray){
  file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('some file.txt');
}
```

The problem is that the **while** loop just does not continue. It seems that if I do not call part.pipe, the loop will halt.

So how can I make the while loop continue?